# Form submission to MongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, mean-stack

[image]I have a form and it consists two buttons "allow" and "reject".I wrote code for the form has to submit when I click either of the buttons.But the case here is along with the form details when I click "allow button" some value has to submitted and when I click "Reject button" someother value has to submitted.what is the approach?

//this is my Template

```
     <button  align="center" type="submit" >Allow</button>
     <button type="submit" >Reject</button>
```

//this is my typescript code

```
   request(ref){
   // console.log(ref.value);


   this.http.post('/api/request',ref.value, 
    {responseType:'text'}).subscribe(data=>{

   })
   }
```

// this is my API

```
   app.post('/request', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

   var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/gateway";
   mongo.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  var dbo = db.db("gateway");
  dbo.collection("vstrinfo").insertOne(req.body);

  })
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll see once.